# Pass Bearer Token from Postman and fetch it value in Magento 2 model

Tags: magento2

I am passing Authorization Bearer Token from postman. i want to fetch that token in magento model.i don't know how to do it ? can anybody help me out ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below code to get the bearer token.

```
public function getAuthToken(){

    $token = false;

    $headers = []; 
    foreach ($_SERVER as $name => $value) 
    { 
        if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'HTTP_') 
        { 
            $headers[str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', substr($name, 5)))))] = $value; 
        } 
    }
    $authorizationBearer = '';

    if(isset($headers['Authorization'])) {
        $authorizationBearer = $headers['Authorization'];
    } else if(isset($headers['authorization'])) {
        $authorizationBearer = $headers['authorization'];
    } else {
        $authorizationBearer = "";
    }

    $authorizationBearerArr = explode(' ', $authorizationBearer);
    if(
        isset($authorizationBearerArr[0]) && 
        trim($authorizationBearerArr[0]) == 'Bearer' && 
        isset($authorizationBearerArr[1])
    ){
        $token = $authorizationBearerArr[1];
    }

    return $token;
}
```

If you still getting any issues let me know.

Thanks

Comment: It's really helpful for me.Thank you so much ZealousWeb.

Comment: Could you please upvote?

Comment: My Dear,I tried upvote, "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." This message displayed

Comment: Okay, thanks. You can vote after 15 reputations.

Answer (score 2):

Declare `\Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request` in construct of your class.

Try the following snippet:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request
 */
protected $request;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request $request
) {
    $this->request = $request;
}
```

Then you can do following:

```
$this->request->getHeader('Authorization'); // To get auth header
```